# Oracle PLSQL table of Object has a parameter that is filled in Oracle 11g, but not filled in Oracle 12c

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, mybatis

A kind of weird problem ...

I have this PL/SQL array :

```
create or replace MY_TYPE_ARRAY 
AS TABLE OF MY_TYPE ;


    create or replace TYPE MY_TYPE AS OBJECT 
( 
  PARAM1          VARCHAR2(100),
  PARAM2          VARCHAR2(35),
  PARAM3          VARCHAR2(35),
  PARAM4          NUMBER(20,2),
  PARAM5          DATE ,
  PARAM6          VARCHAR2(12),
  PARAM7          VARCHAR2(10),
  PARAM8          VARCHAR2(1),
  PARAM9          VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

this array is filled in a java application through a MyBatis TypeHandler :

```
public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, List<MyObject> parameter, JdbcType jdbcType)
        throws SQLException {
    Connection connection = ps.getConnection();
    Struct[] structs = null;
    if (parameter != null && parameter.size() > 0) {
        structs = new Struct[parameter.size()];
        for (int index = 0; index < parameter.size(); index++) {
            MyObject myObject= parameter.get(index);
            Object[] params = new Object[9];
            params[0] = myObject.getParam1();
            params[1] = myObject.getParam2();
            params[2] = myObject.getParam3();
            params[3] = myObject.getParam4();
            params[4] = myObject.getParam5();
            params[5] = myObject.getParam6();
            params[6] = myObject.getParam7();
            params[7] = myObject.getParam8();
            params[8] = myObject.getParam9();
            structs[index] = connection.createStruct("MY_TYPE", params);
        }
        );
    } else {
        parameter = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
        structs = new Struct[0];
    }
    this.parameter = parameter;
    Array oracleArray = ((OracleConnection) connection).createOracleArray("MY_TYPE_ARRAY", structs);
    ps.setArray(i, oracleArray);

}
```

Now the issue is that, after the value is passed to the Stored procedure, the field PARAM3 is sometimes filled correctly and sometimes null :

Stored procedure signature :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MY_PROC (IN_PARAM_1 IN       VARCHAR2,

                                      P_MY_TYPE_LIST         IN      MY_TYPE_ARRAY    
                          )
I INTEGER := 0;
```

The portion of code causing error :

```
FOR MY_OBJ IN P_MY_TYPE_LIST.FIRST .. P_MY_TYPE_LIST.LAST LOOP
                V_STTS := 'S';
                I := I + 1;

                BEGIN

V_TO_IBAN := P_MY_TYPE_LIST(I).PARAM3; //this value is sometimes read correctly, sometimes null though the value is passed correctly from the java

//V_TO_IBAN := P_MY_TYPE_LIST(MY_OBJ).PARAM3; //same behavior
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
```

The issue is in the last line of code as commented, the code runs fine on test environment (oracle 11g) but wrongly on staging (oracle 12c) . Is the issue related to the DB version?

update : jdbc version used : com.oracle:ojdbc8:12.0.2

Comment: Are you sure all the time correct values is passed to the procedure at first place. How did you make sure about that?

Comment: I take the same request exactly from env 2 and pass it to env 1

Comment: I suggest you take Java out of the equation and test purely on the PL/SQL side in SQL Developer or perhaps even livesql.oracle.com, with a simplified set of tables.

Comment: It's working fine using pure PL/SQL

Comment: @osamayaccoub Post your full proc here with the input parameters.